# How to best Javascript code trace in browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, inspector

When I right-click an element in Internet Explorer or Chrome, it takes me to the code, but if there's Javascript referencing an object or function, I want to be able to easily click it some way to just bring me to that object or function where it's instantiated in the code. Right now I have to copy the code and search for it in another tab or section, and it's difficult in IE.

Is there some shortcut (like Ctrl+click in an IDE like Eclipse or PHPStorm) or some feature I'm missing that does this, or is there a plugin or something I can install that would do this or something like it (at least easier than what I have to do now)?

I've been looking around for hours and have tried a few things but it seems like a lost cause.

Answer (score 0):

> When I right-click an element in Internet Explorer or Chrome, it takes me to the code

I don't understand what you mean. What code?

> but if there's Javascript referencing an object or function, I want to be able to easily click it some way to just bring me to that object or function where it's instantiated in the code.

F12 is not an IDE. If you want to find a declaration or reference, use your IDE.

> Is there some shortcut (like Ctrl+click in an IDE like Eclipse or PHPStorm) or some feature I'm missing that does this, or is there a plugin or something I can install that would do this or something like it (at least easier than what I have to do now)?

Not that I'm aware of.

The title of your questions is

> How to best Javascript code trace in browsers?

You can trace code to your heart's content in browsers. That's an entirely different issue from tracking down where functions or objects are declared.